# Can we pass path of the pdf file on cloud in python-PDFBox library to read?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, pdfbox

I have some 800k resumes on google cloud and I want to read each resume through the PDFBox library in python language. But when I give the path to the PDF file like
https://storage.googleapis.com/resume/xyz.pdf

But I am getting the path `error java.io.FileNotFoundException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https:/storage.googleapis.com/resume/xyz.pdf (No such file or directory)`

Does anyone help me out to resolve this error? because I can't download each resume and then read it.

Comment: Clicking on the link brings some XML text.

Comment: forget about the link XML. you can test it on other link address. As this link has resume. so I don't want to share anyone personal details

Comment: Then maybe edit your question to include the code / the call.

Comment: Thank you all. I posted the issue on pdfbox GitHub and they said this library doesn't support any data fetching through the cloud. So I think I have to find some other way.

Comment: there is no issue tracker in "pdfbox github". PDFBox is a java library and can handle files, byte arrays and input streams. The command line applications can handle files.